# Set attribute to a list of data.tables from a list of names

Tags: r, scala, functional-programming, data.table

I am trying to set an attribute for each `data.table` in a list from a list of names, like this:

```
DT = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  a = 1:6,
  b = 7:12,
  c = 13:18
)
DT <- list(DT, DT, DT)
names <- c("NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME3")
sapply(DT, function(x) setattr(x, "name", names))
attr(DT[[1]], "name")
# [1] "NAME1" "NAME2" "NAME3"
sapply(DT, function(x, y) setattr(x, "name", y), names)
attr(DT[[1]], "name")
# [1] "NAME1" "NAME2" "NAME3"
```

But as can be seen, it is the entire list of names what is assigned to each `data.table` in the list.

Is there an FP approach to achieve this? How could I do something similar to what would be in scala:

```
zip(DT, names)
```

and then operate to each pair? I have tried this, with no luck:

```
sapply(list(DT, names), function(x) setattr(x[[1]], "name", x[[2]]))
```

Also, I feel like `sapply` is not the correct function to use here.

## Expected output

```
attr(DT[[1]], "name") # NAME1
attr(DT[[2]], "name") # NAME2
attr(DT[[3]], "name") # NAME3
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: you just wanted to assign names to your list ?

Comment: @RonakShah, to each element of the list, seems like I over complicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set all the names of your data table list using:

```
DT <- setNames(DT, names)
```

note that you need to reasign it to `DT` in order to keep the changes in DT.

Comment: @A.Suliman Yes, `DT <- setNames(DT, names)`, then for each `DT` I have its name: `names(DT[1])  -> NAME1, names(DT[2])  -> NAME2,, names(DT[3])  -> NAME3`

Comment: obviously. You are selecting the names on a concrete data.table, not on a list. Try names(DT) to get the list of names for all data.tables in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, the function you are looking for is `Map` and something like this should have worked

```
Map(function(x, y) setattr(x, "name", y), DT, names)
```

but I don't think you can have attributes with same name for the same object. See this for example,

```
setattr(DT[[1]], "name", names[1])
attr(DT[[1]], "name")
#[1] "NAME1"
```

and now this

```
setattr(DT[[2]], "name", names[2])
attr(DT[[2]], "name")
#[1] "NAME2"
attr(DT[[1]], "name")
#[1] "NAME2"
```